# is it possible to call a function from service in onclick event in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have written a method getDataMethod() in the service 'data.service.ts'.  I want to call this function when someone clicks on a submit button from the html page.

I have created an instance of the service in the constructor of the component, like below:

```
cnstructor(private dataservice: DataService){
    this.data-service-method = this.dataservice.getDataMethod();
}
```

How to call this function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the service inside the constructor of the component, then refer the service and call the method.

```
import { DataService } from './data.service';


export Class ComponentA { 
 constructor(public dataService: DataService) { } 
 myFunct(){
   this.dataService.getDataService().subscribe();
}
}
```

Comment: can't we directly call a method of service without creating instance in component??

Comment: What is "getDataService()"? Angular is telling me that it expects a parameter in the parantheses.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide your service to a parent module or component itself (you can take one other approach in angular v6, take a look at official docs)  and then inject it into your component, then you can use it on `click` or `submit` event.

Component(.ts) file:

```
export class TestComponent {
    constructor(public testService: TestService) {
    }
}
```

Template (.html) file:

```
<button (click)="testService.getDataService()">Button</button>
```

Although it's better if you call the service method from a method declared inside the component.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sajeetharan already mentioned, you will have to call the service from the component.

Check out [this stackblitz POC](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ut2hdz)  which also shows how to import the created service in your module before you can inject it in the component.

> Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Service {

  public getData(): string {
    return "Data From Service";
  }
}
```

> Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { Service } from './service'

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  providers: [Service],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Service } from './service'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    name = 'Angular 6';

    public data: string;

    constructor(private _Service: Service) {

    }

    public getData(): void {
        this.data = this._Service.getData();
    }

}
```

> HTML

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>

<button (click)="getData()">get data</button>

<p> data from service - {{data}} </p>
```